# Negative Match in perl

Tags: perl, regex-negation

I am trying to use negative match in perl.
I want to replace compete word `$FROM` by `$TO` except if

```
.$FROM
```

or

```
. $FROM
```

How to write a expression for this?

I used negative look-ahead regex. But I get following error:

```
Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\.\s*)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many spaces can appear between the `.` and the search value you can chain together fixed-width negative look-behinds. e.g. to handle zero or one space:

```
s/(?<!\.)(?<!\. )$FROM/$TO/;
```

If the number of spaces isn't bound but the search value is a literal string (not a pattern) you can reverse everything, use a negative look-ahead, then reverse the resulting value. e.g.

```
my $rfrom   = reverse $FROM;
my $rto     = reverse $TO;
my $rstring = reverse $string;
$rstring =~ s/$rfrom(?! *\.)/$rto/;
$string = reverse $rstring;
```

If the search value can be a pattern there's no general solution to work around the lack of variable-width negative look-behind.